# How to define SecureLS in React.js to secure session details like JWT token?

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

I have gone through the git for SecureLS, but I find it difficult to define SecureLS in React.

```
var ls = new SecureLS({ encodingType: 'aes' })
```

How can I define like this in React.js class component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React class components, you can create instances of class within `componentDidMount` method in class components and store it in class variable

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     this.ls = new SecureLS({ encodingType: 'aes' })
  }

}
```

Now you can use `ls` anywhere in your class with `this.ls`

**P.S.** Do keep in mind context issues whenever you use `this.ls` in class functions. The `this` inside class functions must refer to the class instance